# Is it possible to $\int\frac{x^2 - 4 }{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 3)} \, dx$ without partial fractions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int\frac{x^2 - 4 }{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 3)} \, dx$$
I did it by partial fractions, I am not typing it here because it is very long, if you want I can.

I want to do it without partial fractions.

Comment: in general no, partial fraction decomposition is the only one method for integrating rational functions (the others, for example the residue theorem, being the same in disguise)

Comment: you may eliminate one of the factors in the denomiator by simply adding $1-1=0$ to the numerator

Answer (score 4):

[Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) won't be that painful if we choose $x^2=y$

$$\dfrac{y-4}{(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)}=\dfrac A{y+1}+\dfrac B{y+2}+\dfrac C{y+3}$$

**Method**$\#1:$
$\implies y-4=A(y+3)(y+2)+\cdots$

Set $y=-1,-2,-3$ one by one to find $A,B,C$

**Method**$\#2:$

$y-4=y^2(A+B+C)+y(5A+4B+3C)+(6A+3B+2C)$
Can you find $A,B,C$ using the facts $$A+B+C=0,5A+4B+3C=1,6A+3B+2C=-4$$

Comment: The OP states, "I want to do it without partial fractions."

Comment: @Dr.MV, I know. But I think that was due tediousness of her/his method

Comment: Lab, that is likely.  And aside from PFE, I don't know of any straightforward approach here.  Do you?  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2 - 4 }{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 3)}=\frac{1.5}{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 2)}-\frac{0.5}{(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 3)}$$
and
$$\frac{1.5}{(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 2)}=\frac{1.5}{(x^2 + 1)}-\frac{1.5}{(x^2 + 2)}$$
$$\frac{0.5}{(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 3)}=\frac{0.5}{(x^2 + 2)}-\frac{0.5}{(x^2 + 3)}$$

Comment: Still I have to go for 6 equation but this time it will comparatively easier to solve.

Comment: Isn't this partial fractions?

Comment: How is this way forward not a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: No , it is not  partial fractions

Comment: @AakashKumar: Note that since $x^2$ occurs everywhere, we can replace it by $w$ and do a partial fractions decomposition. So only three coefficients, not six. Also you can use the "cover up" method to avoid equations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas This will lead to one more term in denominator $x^2=t$ $2xdx=dt$

Comment: @AakashKumar: It will not. After you have done the partial fractions decomposition with $x^2$ everywhere replaced by $w$, replace all the $w$ by $x^2$. You will get the decomposition described in the above answer. **Then** integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd point out the following just in case you've come across this kind of stuff.

If the you instead wanted the value of the integral evaluated over some interval, you could extend it to the complex plane (using something like a semi-circle or rectangle) and then use the residue theorem. Although this method would avoid partial fractions there would probably be just as much algebra needed to manipulate complex numbers!

Comment: And the residues are the coefficient of the partial fraction expansion.